# Can SCOPE_IDENTITY return value after another user's Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Working on a multi-user system, is there any chance that the code below could pick up the id value if another user inserted a row immediately after I did?

```
INSERT INTO table (ross) 
VALUES('whatever');

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY;
```

If so, is there any way I can guarantee that the user gets back the id from the record he/she just entered?

Comment: I added the sql-server tag, because the question appears to be about SQL Server.

Comment: **NO** _ the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is limited to **your** scope - e.g. your transaction and your connection to SQL Server. It is **not** affected by other connections/users inserting values into the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or any other single value mechanisms.

Use [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int);

INSERT INTO table (ross)
    OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @ids  -- use correct column name
    VALUES ('whatever');

SELECT *
FROM ids;
```

Note:

- This works for an arbitrary number of rows being inserted.
- This guarantees that you only get the values back for the rows that were actually inserted by the statement.
- This works even if triggers are defined on the table.
- You can drop the `INTO` and just get the results returned from the `INSERT`.

Comment: For singleton inserts, scope_identity works just fine - and has done so for years.

Comment: @Smor . . . The downvote implies that this answer is *incorrect*.  That seems entirely unwarranted.  `OUTPUT` is the safest way to do what the OP wants -- it works in all situations.

Comment: upvoting the answer because scope_identity is completely oblivious with instead of insert triggers